# Why my string comparison isn't working in bash?

Tags: string, bash, jq, string-comparison

I've a script that does something like this:

```bash
set -x

myJson="echo '{\"data\":\"true\"}'"

commandOutput=$(eval $myJson | jq '.data')

echo $commandOutput

while :
do
    if [[ $commandOutput == "true" ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done

echo "Done"
```

However, my string comparison never works. The only way I managed this to work was putting '"true"' in the string comparison. It seems that is something related to the eval. Since I've set the x flag here is the output of this script:

```
+ myJson='echo '\''{"data":"true"}'\'''
++ eval echo ''\''{"data":"true"}'\'''
+++ echo '{"data":"true"}'
++ jq .data
+ commandOutput='"true"'
+ echo '"true"'
"true"
+ :
+ [[ "true" == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ sleep 1
+ :
+ [[ "true" == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ sleep 1
+ :
+ [[ "true" == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ sleep 1
```

It seems that the string at the right side is being always scaped, if this is the case why is this happening?

Comment: Your JSON contains the **string** `"true"`, not the **boolean** `true`. To decode the JSON string, use the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) flag: `jq -r '.data'`.

Comment: Oh, now everything makes sense.

Comment: As a slight aside, what's the reason for storing a command to `eval`, instead of using something like `myJson=$(echo ...)` assuming `echo` as the placeholder for something more complex, or even directly `myJson='{"data": ... }'`?

Comment: Just to emphasize the problem for future users: the length of the commandOutput value is 6 characters -- it contains literal quote characters. The right-hand side of the equality comparison is only 4 characters. Thus they are unequal

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: A line like `eval $myJson | jq '.data'` demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of quotes.   A string like `.data` does not need to be quoted.  Variables generally should be quoted.  Ignoring the issue of using `eval` at all, this would be better written `eval "$myJson" | jq .data` (Although there is no harm quote .data and writing `jq ".data"` or `jq '.data'`, it is not necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the trace which you have posted, `commandOutput` does not hold the string `true`, but the string `"true"`, so you have to test for this:

```
 [[ $commandOutput == '"true"' ]]
```